# Pytorch, When I use backward() in the loop, the message failed on the second loop

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I use loops to propagate forward and backward through my model. However, I encounter an error notification during the second loop with the following message:

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

I've explored various methods available on the network, ensuring that I don't employ backpropagation twice in one loop. It doesn't seem like there's a point to release the graph.

I have tried my best to check the error, but there is still no solution. This is my first time in S.O. Please forgive me if there is anything unclear in the description.

The code in question is as follows (not all shown because I don't think it's necessary)

```py
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss().type(data_type) 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate) 

image_queue = queue.Queue()
# a separate thread for calculating a value that is used by a main thread
denoise_thread = Thread(target=lambda q, f, p: q.put(f(*p)),  # q -> queue, f -> func, p -> params
                        args=(image_queue, non_local_means,
                              [benchmark_image.clone().squeeze().cpu().detach().numpy(), 3]))
denoise_thread.start()

temp_benchmark = benchmark_image.clone()  #  copy of the benchmark for intermediate calculations
for i in range(num_iter + 1):

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    out = net(net_input)
    temp = benchmark_image - lagrange_multiplier
    loss_net = criterion(out, decrease_image)     # this loss backward normally
    loss_red = criterion(out, temp)               # this is where things go wrong

    total_loss = loss_net + mu * loss_red
    total_loss.backward()                         # FAIL backward!!!

    # updates the benchmark value every iteration a certain number of times
    if i % 30 == 0:
        denoise_thread.join()
        temp_benchmark = image_queue.get()
        temp_benchmark = torch.from_numpy(temp_benchmark)[None, :].cuda()
        temp_benchmark.requires_grad_()
            
        # as before, it is used to update values that will be used by the main thread
        denoise_thread = Thread(target=lambda q, f, p: q.put(f(*p)),
                                args=(image_queue, non_local_means,
                                      [benchmark_image.clone().squeeze().cpu().detach().numpy(), 3]))
        denoise_thread.start()

    benchmark_image = 1 / (beta + mu) * (beta * temp_benchmark + mu * (out + lagrange_multiplier))
    lagrange_multiplier = lagrange_multiplier + out - benchmark_image

    optimizer.step()
       
if denoise_thread.is_alive():
    denoise_thread.join()
```

I've been grappling with this issue for several days, and if there's any part of my description that is unclear, please let me know. Your assistance is greatly appreciated! ;-)

---

Thanks to all the kind people who offered help, after I tried to modify the code repeatedly, I found a way to solve the problem, which is to directly empty an input gradient value of loss, as shown below:

```py
loss_red = criterion(out, temp.detach_())  # What a simple but wonderful solution
```

Although this has solved the problem, I still don't know why this problem occurs, perhaps someone can tell me the reason.

Anyway, it is a pleasure to have this trouble solved. LOL

Comment: Have you tried to use the retain_graph option?
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-is-retain-graph-true-needed-in-some-case-but-not-in-other/161705

Comment: yep, i tried to use the retain_graph option, it made the code work for a short time, but the video memory quickly overflowed, which I don't think is the right solution @Domenico

Comment: But that may derive from other portions of the code, which now get executed and lead to this memory overflow. Are you sure that your model has no memory leaks? how does it behaves without calculating loss_red? any memory leak?

Comment: when only loss_net is computed (for loss_net.backward()), the code will work without retain_graph and without memory overflow

Comment: and by using only loss_red? in other words, without computing loss_net

Comment: The problem occurs when only loss_red is used, and the same problem occurs when total_loss is used, I mean I suspect loss_red is the problem

Comment: Indeed. I see that the "lagrange_multiplier", used for loss_red, depends on the previous "lagrange_multiplier" value: this can explain why the graph becomes larger and larger over time. Have you tried putting a dummy *constant* value for it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the "lagrange_multiplier" had an initial value, and I set it to an all-0 tensor of the specified size, and I kept it the same size during the calculation

Comment: It is about the history of calculations. If you set `lagrange_multiplier` to a fixed value at each iteration, then the computational graph doesn't need to backtrace all the previous operations that have been done on `lagrange_multiplier`. See my answer below on stackoverflow for better clarity

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem arises from adding the `out` to the `lagrange_multiplier` with gradients on.

This way, when you call `loss.backward()` on a calculation that contains the `lagrange_multiplier`, pytorch will try to calculate gradients again for the output of the model which explains the error of `Trying to backward through the graph a second time`.

I am not familiar with your problem and whether this is intended behaviour but a simple fix would be to turn off the gradients when updating the `lagrange_multiplier`:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    lagrange_multiplier = lagrange_multiplier + out - benchmark_image
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it still reported the same error

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch prompts the need to retrace the graph during the backward pass because the `lagrange_multiplier` variable depends on all previous iterations of the `for` loop. If `lagrange_multiplier` were independent of previous iterations (e.g., using `lagrange_multiplier = out - benchmark_image` instead of `lagrange_multiplier = lagrange_multiplier + out - benchmark_image`... note that `benchmark_image` suffers the same, as it depends on `lagrange_multiplier`), the training would proceed without PyTorch requesting graph retracing or increasing memory requirements, as the computational graph wouldn't need to trace the entire history.

One solution that comes to mind, while preserving the intent of that line of code, is the following code that **truncate the history** of `lagrange_multiplier`. So, instead of:

```
benchmark_image = 1 / (beta + mu) * (beta * temp_benchmark + mu * (out + lagrange_multiplier))
lagrange_multiplier = out - benchmark_image + lagrange_multiplier
```

you use:

```
benchmark_image = 1 / (beta + mu) * (beta * temp_benchmark + mu * (out + previous_lagrange_multiplier))
lagrange_multiplier = out - benchmark_image + previous_lagrange_multiplier
previous_lagrange_multiplier = lagrange_multiplier.detach().clone().requires_grad_(False)
```

of course, do not forget to initialise the `previous_lagrange_multiplier`

Comment: I tried it as soon as I saw your comment, but the problem remained, but I found a solution to the problem, and I updated at the back of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it using below. It is because you are using same **criterion** variable for calculating loss and it is updating the same computational graph when calculating loss_red after loss_net

Use two criterions as below

```
criterion1 =  torch.nn.MSELoss().type(data_type) 
criterion2 =  torch.nn.MSELoss().type(data_type)
loss_net   = criteria1(out, decrease_image) 
loss_red = criterion2(out, temp)
```

Also I am not sure if performing arithmetic on loss will work

```
total_loss = loss_net + mu * loss_red
total_loss.backward()
```

I think it might not work since total_loss is a new variable not in the computation graph. This will likely give you error.
You might have to create a custom loss function using nn.Module and use that custom loss here.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, mu, data_type):
        super(CustomLoss, self).__init__()
        self.criterion1 = nn.MSELoss().type(data_type)
        self.criterion2 = nn.MSELoss().type(data_type)
        self.mu = mu

    def forward(self, out, decrease_image, temp):
        loss1 = self.criterion1(out, decrease_image)
        loss2 = self.criterion2(out, temp)

        total_loss = loss1 + self.mu * loss2 
        return total_loss
```

Comment: I tried two loss functions, but it still reported the same error

Comment: Then I think it is the total_loss where you combine two losses, please try using the custom loss I updated in answer. Thank you! @KikkiZhang

Comment: The problem is still not solved. I think there is a problem in the calculation of the second loss value, because I can use backward() of the first loss, but not the second loss.

Comment: @KikkiZhang If you use custom loss, there is no need to use second loss, you can use a single custom loss and use loss.backward()

Comment: I know what you mean, but what I'm saying is that the fault lies with the second loss, whether custom loss is used or not, so I don't think it's a matter of whether or not the two MSELoss are calculated separately